# NGINX, THe Edge, HAPRoxy

Tags: node.js, nginx, load-balancing, haproxy

I was going through Uber Engineering website where I came across this paragraph and I it confused me a lot, if anyone can make it clear for me then I would be thankful to him/her:

> The Edge The frontline API for our mobile apps consists of over 600
>   stateless endpoints that join together multiple services. It routes
>   incoming requests from our mobile clients to other APIs or services.
>   It’s all written in Node.js, except at the edge, where our NGINX front
>   end does SSL termination and some authentication. The NGINX front end
>   also proxies to our frontline API through an HAProxy load balancer.

[**This is the link.**](https://eng.uber.com/tech-stack-part-two/)

NGINX is already a reverse proxy + load balancer, then from where HAProxy load balancer came in the picture and where exactly it fits in the picture? What is "the edge" he talked about? Either the guy who wrote his he wrote confused words or I dont know English.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like they're using HAProxy strictly as a load balancer, and using NGINX strictly to terminate SSL and for authentication. It isn't necessary in most cases to use HAProxy along with NGINX, as you mentioned, NGINX has load-balancing capabilities, but being Uber, they probably ran into some unique problems that required the use of both. According to the information I've read, such as http://www.loadbalancer.org/blog/nginx-vs-haproxy/ and https://thehftguy.com/2016/10/03/haproxy-vs-nginx-why-you-should-never-use-nginx-for-load-balancing/, NGINX works extremely well as a web server, including the use case where it is serving as a reverse proxy for a node application, but its load-balancing capabilities are basic and not nearly as performant as HAProxy. Additionally, HAProxy exposes many more metrics for monitoring, and has more advanced routing capabilities.

Load balancing is not the core feature of NGINX. In the context of a node.js application, usually what you would see NGINX used for is to serve as a reverse proxy, meaning that NGINX is the web server, and http requests come through it. Then, based on the hostname and other rules, it forwards on the HTTP request to whatever port your node.js application is running on. As part of this flow, often NGINX will handle SSL termination, so that this computationally-intensive task is not being handled by node.js. Additionally, NGINX is often used to serve static assets for node.js apps, as it is more efficient, especially when compressing assets.

Comment: Can you make a guess what could have gone wrong or what could be their "urge" to do it that way?

Comment: If NGINXs load balancing capabilities are very basic then why are they using NGINX at all?

Comment: Updated my answer with some thoughts (guesses) about why someone might be interested in using NGINX without relying on its load-balancing capabilities.

Comment: "and using NGINX strictly to terminate SSL and for authentication" - How do you mean by "Authentication" ?

Comment: https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/configuring-http-basic-authentication/
https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/configuring-jwt-authentication/